# Xcode 4.5 device orientation change?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am in the process of building a cocos2d game with kobold2d and since I upgraded to xcode 4.5 every time I build the project the device orientation starts out in landscape and the rotates to portrait mode automatically? I in the precious versions of xcode the default orientation is landscape but now it keeps switching on its own.

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you running?

Comment: cocos2d v1.1.0 This is in kobold2d just so you know.

Comment: same problem here. have you tried the new version of cocos?

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate change the line that says something like:

```
[window addSubView:viewcontroller.view];

to

[window setRootViewController:viewcontroller];
```

that should do it.

Comment: Fixed it for ios6 but messed up 5 instead.